# FancyBox text inputs disabled

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have just started using FancyBox and am currently trying to create a series of input fields within. I have found with the following code (extremely trimmed down to try and figure out what is wrong) that when the FancyBox displays, the **input[type='text']** element is not editable and I am not sure why.

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="divFancyBoxTest">
    <input type="text" id="something" value="test" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$.fancybox.open($("#divFancyBoxTest"));
```

..In the following image the input control is not accessible.

[image]

Does anyone know why this is? I have been poring over all CSS and related code and I can't figure out why this is happening.

fancyBox v2.1.4

Comment: The code you've shown us won't do that, so something else must be doing it.  It's not going to be CSS as you can't change the disabled state of a control through a stylesheet.  Do you have any more JS we could see?

Comment: unfortunately too much to post. any markers i can look out for in code? attr("disabled", "disabled") or anything like that?

Comment: I just added the following control.. disabled as well.. <textarea>sdfds</textarea>

Comment: I'd start with a search for the words disable and enabled.  Is this on a public server so we could look at it?

Comment: no instances of disable, disabled, enable, enabled. no unfortunately just on dev machine.

Comment: i tested the code on another page and it worked. so you must be correct. ill have to start ripping out code and seeing what happens. if you write as an answer ill mark as correct. thanks.

Comment: i think ive got it. the fancybox was launched from a jquery dialog. as it was modal - it disabled everything else.

Comment: Makes sense.  Glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/uZCC6/2263/

```
$.fancybox.open([{
    content: $('#divFancyBoxTest').html(),
    title: 'Input box'
}, ], {
    padding: 0
});
```

Comment: `$.fancybox.open('#divFancyBoxTest');` or ` $.fancybox.open($("#divFancyBoxTest"));` do the same http://jsfiddle.net/UYHxc/ or http://jsfiddle.net/UYHxc/1